# What is a correct way to use array key on if conditions in Handlebar templates?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm using this register helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function (v1, operator, v2, options) {

    switch (operator) {
        case '==':
            return (v1 == v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '===':
            return (v1 === v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '<':
            return (v1 < v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '<=':
            return (v1 <= v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '>':
            return (v1 > v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '>=':
            return (v1 >= v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '&&':
            return (v1 && v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        case '||':
            return (v1 || v2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
        default:
            return options.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

And loop over data options, which are:

```
var dataOptions = {
    number: "Number",
    string: "String",
    bool: "Boolean",
    none: "Null/None"
}
```

where I just want to mark checked options like this:

```
{{#each dataOptions}}
    <option value="{{@key}}"{{#ifCond @key '==' element.data}} checked="checked"{{/ifCond}}>{{this}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

But condition doesn't seem to work. I wonder if it is because of using @key inside helper or what?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your `dataOptions` is an array. `@key` is for objects and `@index` is for arrays, try changing your code to:

```
{{#each dataOptions}}
    <option value="{{@index}}"{{#ifCond @index '==' element.data}} checked="checked"{{/ifCond}}>{{this}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

Also node that the `each` block will create a new scope so you might need to reference `element.data` with `../element.data`

---

For debugging you can add `console.log(arguments);` as the first line in your custom helper function:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function (v1, operator, v2, options) {

    console.log(arguments); // <-- could also use `debugger` if you want a breakpoint when the helper is called.

    switch (operator) {
    // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for tips. dataOptions were an object, but changing element.data to ../element.data and checked="checked" -> selected="selected" made the trick!